# Invalidar caracteres de um MaskFormatter

Tags: java, swing

Então galera, tenho uma janela onde preciso passar por uma validação de campos nulos de diversos `JTextField` e um `JFormattedTextField`, onde este último possui uma máscara para números de telefone `"(##)####-####"`. O fato é que mesmo eu não digitando nada nesse campo, ele pega os caracteres da máscara : `()-` e entende que o campo não está nulo. Gostaria de saber se não há algum método que ignore caracteres de uma máscara, ou vou ter que fazer todo aquele trampo com `substring` ? Vale deixar claro que eu apenas quero ignorar na hora da validação, e não remover esses caracteres, pois depois terei que apresentá-los ao usuário !

Como instancio :

```
try {
        mskTel = new MaskFormatter("(##)####-####");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    txtTel = new JFormattedTextField(mskTel);
```

Como é feita a validação :

```
form.txtTel.getText() == null || form.txtTel.getText().trim().isEmpty()
```

Comment: Como você está pegando os valores deste campo? Adicione um [mcve] para que possamos analisar o problema.

Comment: Uma solução "porca" seria verificar o tamanho da string retornada, seu campo deveria ter 13 caracteres, logo `form.txtTel.getText() = form.txtTel.getText().trim().length == 13 ? form.txtTel.getText().trim() : null`.

Comment: quando aplico essa solução dá erro de compilação : "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable". Dai se eu tento atribuir o `form.txtTel.getText()` à uma String, ele acusa outro erro, e sugere que eu adicione um `()` após o `.length`, e a partir daí, a validação não funciona mais ...

Comment: Foi mal, erro meu. O correto é atribuir a uma variável string: `String text = form.txtTel.getText().trim().length == 13 ? form.txtTel.getText().trim() : null`

Comment: Mas esse comando eu coloco antes da validação, ou substituo o trecho correspondente ?

Comment: Onde você faz essa validação? Num if?

Comment: Exatamente ! Veja o trecho do código : http://pastebin.com/krFV37Vc

Comment: Basta substituir a validação do empty: http://pastebin.com/H04xkm9Z